# Count of each type of label in a column of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I have a following data frame. I need to find count of each type of MNTPCODE for each donor.

```
    CONTID  MEDIUMCODE  MNTOPCODE   CLASCODE    EXTRELNO    CONTDIREC   CONTDATE
   000405402     CI        CTS        CT         0000020       O           1994-05-09
    000430904   CI       CTS          CT         0000020        O       1994-06-14
   000592732    CI       CTS          CT        0000020         O       1994-10-21
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `DataFrame.groupby(index)` with `.size()`

I added extra row with 'FAKECODE' for better understanding

`df`
:

```
      CONTID MEDIUMCODE MNTOPCODE CLASCODE EXTRELNO CONTDIREC    CONTDATE
0  000405402         CI       CTS       CT  0000020         O  1994-05-09
1  000430904         CI       CTS       CT  0000020         O  1994-06-14
2  000592732         CI       CTS       CT  0000020         O  1994-10-21
3  000592733         CI  FAKECODE       CT  0000020         O  1994-10-21
```

then used `df.groupby('MNTOPCODE').size()`
=>

```
MNTOPCODE
CTS         3
FAKECODE    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! But i need to find out type of code for each donor.

Comment: Could you specify details of your data? I can't understand what each column mean and what the 'code', 'donors' are. Give me a sample format you want.

Comment: here donor is the person who is donating to an NGO : donor-id is  mentioned in column (EXTRELNO) . MNTOPCODE is the column which shows topic of communication. A donor can contact for different reasons. I need to know how many times a donor is contacting for each reason.

Comment: i need result in following format.  `EXTRELNO   MNTOPCODE   COUNT`